# using regular expression to match the last word of a substring

Tags: c#, regex

I need to match one word in a sentence which can be almost anything. The sentence looks similar to the following:

The old man walks today for a long time.

In the sentence "the blind man" could be anything and may be one or more words, "today" could be anything but is always one word and "for a long time." is always the same.
I am trying to get "walks" which is a different word each time.

What I have tried is this:
    (.+)(?= .+ for a long time.)

Which gets me "The old man walks"

What I was trying to do from there is get the last word of that substring but I don't know what to add to the regular expression to get it. Would it be better to just use substring methods for this?

edit: wrote the wrong word that I was looking for, corrected in the above text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match the whole thing and group only the one that you care about in ( ). Like this:

```
string s = "^.* ([^ ]+) for a long time\\.$";

Regex r = new Regex(s);
Match m = r.Match("The old man walks today for a long time.");
if(m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: This returned nothing when I tried to run this were you trying to give me a general idea or should this string work?

Comment: Petar is right, but he forgot the period just before the dollar sign. See here: http://www.rubular.com/r/ueZDH6Bfur

Comment: I was unaware of the m.Groups values, but I see it places your groups in there. Thank you!

Comment: Okay I messed up and said I was looking for the wrong word I meant to say I was looking for the word in the position of "walk" which could be a different word every time.

Comment: Your code helped me find my answer which is: "^.* ([^ ]+) .+ for a long time.$"